# How to make the header of modal window fixed at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a modal window using html , css and Jquery .
Whenever the modal content is long , scrolling down  makes the modal header go to very top

I want the modal header to stay at its original place ( as in fixed ) even if the content is scrolled down

I tried using - position: fixed for css class modal-header as a random try and it's not working as expected

I am attaching the codes in snippets

```
$(function () {
  const openModals = [];
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).show());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')}, 400);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open>* {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.modal .open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
             Modal Header
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
           What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest instead of fixing header `provide scroll to body` because model `popup` have `fixed position` so better to scroll body. check snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  const openModals = [];
  $('.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).show());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {
        closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')
      }, 400);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
    $('.modal-body').scrollTop(0);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 95px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 3.125rem;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #171B20;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #888;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.375rem 1.25rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 52px);
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  from {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.modal-content-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: animateBottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animateBottom;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #F0B823;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.25rem;
  top: -0.25rem;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.248em 0.496em;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.750rem;
  margin: 0.124em 0.062em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 50vh;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.bodytext {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.625em 0.9375em;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open>* {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.modal {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.modal .open {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.bold {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">• Click Me</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext header-fixed">
        Modal Header
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
        What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's indeed working well and exactly what i wanted. Just on a side note. Can you tell me how you arrived at height values like ( 100vh - 95px ) for modal body and ( 100vh - 52px ) for height of modal-content

Comment: good to here that its helped. 100vh will be you screen resolution minus your top space which is around those number. please do accept and up vote the answer :).

Comment: 52px from top to where the model start and 95 from top to where the model header ends. up vote will be helpful.

Comment: thanks understood it well , by the way is it possible that when we close a modal window and reopen it , it starts from the top like usual not the area where we have last scrolled at...

Comment: When this body scroll wasn't implemented , by default no matter how many times you open a modal , it always started from the top

Comment: you need to add the "$('.modal-body').scrollTop(0);" to your java script. check updated snippet.

Comment: hello sir , sorry for extending it a little but currently even if a modal is 5 lines of text , its taking the whole page page  Earlier if a modal content was short it would end right then and there as height wasn't explicitly defined. Is it possible to have that thing while retaining the body scroll for long content you have implementated through this answer

Comment: Instead of height use max-height will help you. Right now not able to update the snippet but will do it tomorrow.

Comment: sure i  will try doing it on my own , and can wait till you update  if i couldn't  ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution and updated code below - https://www.codeply.com/go/5bPnwA4WKn

you just need to update modal-body as below then add z-index property for model-header so it appears on top.

```
.modal-body {
        overflow-y:scroll;        
        position: absolute;
        height : 450px;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 0.125rem 1rem;
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
  z-index : 1;

}
```